# Updating version of ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have ckeditor version 4.4.2 on my site
and I would like to update to the current one (4.4.7)

Is it enough to just replace the `ckeditor.js` file? I cant remember if my site has the Standard or Full version installed.

Thanks

Comment: See the [official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_upgrade). You got to replace **all** the files.

Comment: And you can check your build in `build-config.js` file included in the package. You can even redownload this package (but with a latest version of CKE) using links included in the build config file.

Comment: thanks guys - both answers were helpful